# How to set a custom DNS server with Java 8 and Open-JDK?

Tags: java

How to set a custom DNS server with Java 8 and Open-JDK to resolves hostnames? I tried the following from the other stackoverflow post but it doesn't seem to work for open-jdk-8. any ideas?

```
 System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", "100.68.0.50");
 System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");
```

`100.68.0.50` is my dns-server

Answer (score 0):

The properties should be set before anything instantiates an `InetAddress`, as the name service is statically created.

Note that many seemingly innocuous statements like having a static logger in your main class can result in creating  `InetAddress` objects under the hood, and thus initializing the name service.

Does it work when you use `java -D...=...`?